# Which version of jdk can i use for building a maven project?

Tags: maven-3

I'm going to build a maven project for the first time. I downloaded maven- 3.1.1 and I want to know if I can use jdk 1.7.0._05. If there is any other version that I need to use, please do specify.

Thanks :)

Comment: That will work just fine. Of course, you can verify that by just doing it and then coming back here with any problems you have. Good luck learning Maven (although I've become a [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) fan myself)!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't any version that you are forced to use to build Maven project. You can simply run:

```
mvn -version
```

to see what version is used currently by Maven. This version should match the JDK you have set as JAVA_HOME, so in case if you want to change it, simply change your JAVA_HOME to different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [System Requirements](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#System_Requirements) noted at the [download](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) page:

**JDK:**    1.5 or above (this is to execute Maven - it still allows you to build against 1.3 and prior JDK's)